# Error Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token B in JSON at position 0 at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json, jsonobject

se que hay varias preguntas similares pero igual la hare porque a pesar de leerlas no encuentro una que resuelva mi error.

Estoy tratando de pasarle los valores de una consulta en php a JSON para mostrarlos en la pantalla del navegador, en el index... estoy usando este codigo, la consulta es correcta, obtiene los datos ya lo comprobe en la consola de hecho el array que guada los datos es correcto este es el archivo php con la consulta

```
<?php 
include('database.php');

$search = $_POST['search'];

if (!empty($search)) {
    $query = "SELECT * FROM task WHERE name LIKE '%$search%'";
    $result = mysqli_query($con, $query);

    if (!$result) {
        die('Query Error'.mysqli_error($con));
    }

    $json = array();
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
        $json[] = array(
            'name' => $row['name'],
            'description' => $row['description'],
            'id' => $row['id']
        );
    }
    $jsonstring = json_encode($json);
    echo $jsonstring;
}
```

Luego pido estos valores con ajax para ser mostrados en pantalla en mi archivo js

```
$(document).ready(function() {

console.log('Jquery funcionando');

//Mostrar la lista
    $.ajax({
        url: 'task_list.php',
        type: 'GET',
        success: function (response){
            let tasks = JSON.parse(response);
            let template = '';
            tasks.forEach(task => {
                template += `
                <tr>
                    <td>${task.id}</td>
                    <td>${task.name}</td>
                    <td>${task.description}</td>
                </tr>
                `
            });
            $('#task').html(template);
        }
    });
```

});

Me indica el error desde que empieza el success, ya intente poniendo el JSON.parse("["response"]") para darle el formato que realmente pide pero al hacerlo de esta manera me arroja undefined en los items que deberia mostrar... anexo captura del error[image: imagen descriptiva]